# PHP Conditional -- Only Display if a String Has Any Value?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I need to display the results of either one or two strings.  Each string contains a comma-separated list of items.  I need to concatenate them into a single list.

I know how to do the concatenation.

The issue I have is that sometimes the second string contains entries, sometimes it does not.

If the second string contains data, I want to display the concatenated result (first string and second string).  If the second string is empty, I only want to display the first string.

Can someone help me figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: Always post the example code that you've been working with, to give others a better visualization of what you're attempting to do. Thanks! :)

Comment: have you ever heard about `if` ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I know this has something to do with a conditional.  But I don't know how to form it.

Comment: If you concat with an empty string... isn't that the same as not displaying it? I cannot fathom what the issue is. Were you looking for `trim($str, ',')`? Maybe `I know how to do the concatenation` is not completely true? Can we see your code?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  What I meant is, I know how to make concat work, though I think other methods described below make it unnecessary.  Thank you for helping.  It's really valuable to get different views and opinions.

Comment: @MatthewSchenker: The best possible input and help you could have gotten would have required that you show your actual code. I feel that you've done yourself a disservice.

Comment: I understand your point.  But I didn't have anything up front.  All I knew is that it needed some kind of conditional.  As it turned out, the best answer looked nothing like what I was thinking. I was asking an honest question about code, but didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call me crazy, but …

```
echo $string1;
if($string2 != '') {
  echo ', ', $string2;
}
```

should be enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string1 = 'test1,test2';
$string2 = 'test3,test4';

if(isset($string2) && strlen($string2) > 0)
    echo($string1 . ',' . $string2);
else echo($string1);

$string2 = '';

if(isset($string2) && strlen($string2) > 0)
    echo($string1 . ',' . $string2)
else echo($string1);
```

Or, if you want a terse statement with the ternary operator:

```
$string1 = 'test1,test2';
$string2 = 'test3,test4';

echo $string1 . ($string2 ? ',' . $string2 : '');

unset($string2);

echo $string1 . ($string2 ? ',' . $string2 : '');
```

Comment: Thanks watcher!  Sorry for the simple question, but you're showing me two different methods for doing this, right?

Comment: No, I'm showing you one method with two examples.  One where your second string is not empty and one where it is.

Comment: i really don't think it is necessary to check the variable using isset() or strlen() function because if the variable is not declared or if it is empty string, then it is automatically evaluated to false.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar I think it depends on the application.  You want to make sure the variable is set before trying to pass it to the `strlen` function, and if the string undergoes some kind of processing before the section of code where this is applicable then it could start off with a value and wind up being trimmed down to nothing for whatever reason.  Personally, my sanity is worth a few clock cycles every now and then.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: that's wrong on many levels. first: creating undefined variable notices is bad practice. second: `"0"` also evaluates to false.